# asp.net _Layout.cshtml only load scripts if model is of type ______

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I only load scripts in my _Layout.cshtml if the model is of a certain type? I only want my layout to load the scripts tag if the model is of a custom model type I made.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via razor syntax in your view

```
   @if(Model is <yourtypehere>)
    {
          <script>alert('this is my type')</script>
          //or you can even
          <script src="myjavascriptfilelocation"/>    
    }
```